# Is there a way to add members to a slack channnel from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to add members to a slack channel who have breached some baselines during the build process in a Jenkins job. I was able to integrate and send messages to the channel, but not aware of where to strike for adding members to a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite) in a Jenkins job and take the user name as a parameter.